# Tabulator 'autocomplete' issue

Tags: tabulator

I noticed that if I use `editor:'autocomplete'` it is impossible to push the enter button to select a value from the dropdown list.

For example (http://tabulator.info/examples/4.7?#editable):

[image]

If I write `Cana` and press `Enter`, the cell value does not change from the `United Kingdom` to `Canada`. I need to manually select `Canada` from the list.

Maybe there is a way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: The autocompletes I have worked with or use exhibit this behavior as they cannot be certain what your intent is. In your case what if Canary Islands was also choice? Should ```Cana``` resolve to it or Canada? In the above case selection is down arrow then enter. There is no 'fix' I'm aware, short of writing your own version of the editor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !
I agree with it only when the length of the list > 1 ['Canada','Canary Islands' ] , but if the list has only one iniq value , why do I need to push down arrow and then enter? On my mind when user writes 'Canad', he thinks about Canada in 99% of cases , in other situations he can select from the list.

Comment: Because it is presented as  list and you need to navigate the list first. If you want that behavior to change you would need to file an issue here:https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues or write a patch yourself and submit it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how the ***autocomplete*** editor works im afraid.

You must move the cursor down to select an item in the list first before you can then hit enter to choose it.

Once you have selected an item it should work as normal.

An example of the editor in action can be found on the Location column on the [Editors Example](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.7#editable)